# Codeigniter: submit form data without page refreshing with jQuery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have tried to submit a form data in codeigniter framework with ajax jQuery without page refreshing but it always pass to `fail` message.

I'm new to ajax, help me to solve this error.

**Here is my Controller:**

```
public function add_personal() {
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $jid = $this->Jsprofile->get_jsid($id)->jobseeker_id;
    $data = array(
        'js_personal_title' => $this->input->post('js_personal_title'),
        'js_personal_desc' => $this->input->post('js_personal_desc'),
        'tbl_jobseeker_jobseeker_id' => $jid,
        'tbl_jobseeker_tbl_user_u_id'=>$id
        );
   // echo json_encode($data);
    $this->load->database();
    $this->db->insert('tbl_js_personal',$data);  
}
```

**Here is my view:**

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="personal-info" class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="js_personal_title">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="js_personal_desc">
      <input id="submit-p" class="form-control" type="submit" value="Add">
</form>
```

**Here is js code :-**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#personal-info").submit(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
          var data= $("#personal-info").serializeArray();
           $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: 'http://localhost/joblk.com/index.php/jobseeker/add_personal',
              data: data,
         success:function(data)  {
           alert('SUCCESS!!');
            },
 error: function (XHR, status, response) {
           alert('fail');
             }
            });
      });
  });
```

**Model for get values:**

```
    public function get_jsid($id) {
 $sql = "SELECT jobseeker_id FROM tbl_jobseeker WHERE tbl_user_u_id = ".$id.";";
            return  $this->db->query($sql)->row();
        }
```

Comment: Please check your `browser's console` for errors.

Comment: You are not passing `jobseeker_id` in your ajax url  `url: 'http://localhost/joblk.com/index.php/jobseeker/add_personal',`

Comment: @Abdulla still its coming to error

Comment: Ty to check your error with console.log(); to find your error or response in firebug console or browser console

Comment: `console.log(data);` add this to both success and error function to see the browser console, and also change the error function as Abdulla mentioned above.

Comment: @sa-7 nothing is appearing than fail message

Comment: @Abdulla `add_personal` has no arguments to pass

Comment: Try this in error function: `console.log(status);`

Comment: so what you trying to get with `$id = $this->uri->segment(3);`

Comment: @Abdulla its for get the `$jid`,  that I'm collecting values to insert

Comment: so how your URL look like add that to. Will give solution

Comment: @Abdulla url doesn't change, its like `http://localhost/joblk.com/index.php/main/profile/000037`

Comment: Change your button input type from submit to button and trigger the submit javascript function using onclick event instead of .submit. you should be done.

Comment: Still, the same answer is getting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In AJAX**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#personal-info").submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var title = $("#js_personal_title").val();;
            var decs= $("#js_personal_desc").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/jobseeker/add_personal',
                data: {title:title,decs:decs},
                success:function(data)
                {
                    alert('SUCCESS!!');
                },
                error:function()
                {
                    alert('fail');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**in form (add `id` attribute)**

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="personal-info" class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="js_personal_title" name="js_personal_title">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="js_personal_desc" name="js_personal_desc">
    <input id="submit-p" class="form-control" type="submit" value="Add">
</form>
```

**In controller**

```
    function add_personal()
    {
        $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
        //im confusing this part
        $jid = $this->Jsprofile->get_jsid($id);

        $data = array(
            'js_personal_title' => $this->input->post('title'),
            'js_personal_desc' => $this->input->post('decs'),
            'tbl_jobseeker_jobseeker_id' => $jid[0]['jobseeker_id'],
            'tbl_jobseeker_tbl_user_u_id'=>$id
        );
        // echo json_encode($data);

        $this->db->insert('tbl_js_personal',$data);
    }
```

**In model**

```
function get_jsid($id)
{

    $query =  $this->db->query("SELECT jobseeker_id FROM tbl_jobseeker WHERE tbl_user_u_id = '$id'");
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result;
}
```

in `config/autoload.php`

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

Comment: no URI segment is 3 because CI ignore that `index.php` and I already echo and checked that.

Comment: i did still the same answer

Comment: what you trying to  get with this `$jid = $this->Jsprofile->get_jsid($id)->jobseeker_id;`

Comment: value for the MySQL column `tbl_jobseeker_jobseeker_id` and i checked that with echo

Comment: did you check model is working ?? cz model name should be `Jsprofile_model`

Comment: ok show me code inside model related `get_jsid`. Edit on your question

Comment: some changes have been done in **controller** and **model**. change that

Comment: No it cant be, Check your data passing to `$id`, echo it and check

Comment: `$id` is OK it should be segment 3, though still the same answer

Comment: When I passed data to the error message its giving `[object Object]`

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

**View**

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="personal-info" class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control"  id="uri_segment_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $this->uri->segment(3); ?>">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="js_personal_title">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="js_personal_desc">
      <input id="submit-p" class="form-control" type="submit" value="Add">
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#personal-info").submit(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
         var id = $('#uri_segment_id').val(); 
          var data= $("#personal-info").serializeArray();
               $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                    url: 'http://localhost/joblk.com/index.php/jobseeker/add_personal/'+id,
                   data: data,
                success:function(data)  {
                               alert('SUCCESS!!');
                },
                error: function (XHR, status, response) {
                                console.log(status+' --- '+' --- ' + response);
                }
            });
      });
  });
```

Comment: No, there is no changing in URL

Comment: have you tried  `$("#submit-p").click(function(e)` in this way?

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
 <script  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submit-p").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var title = $("#js_personal_title").val();;
            var decs= $("#js_personal_desc").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/jobseeker/add_personal',
                data: {title:title,decs:decs},
                success:function(data)
                {
                    alert('SUCCESS!!');
                },
                error:function()
                {
                    alert('fail');
                }
            });
        });
    });

            </script>
```

Just try adding the above jquery scripts too.And also try to echo your result in the model or controller so that you can make sure no error on controller and model, and the return result whether any json issues?

in Controller

```
function add_personal()
    {
        $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
        //im confusing this part
        $jid = $this->Jsprofile->get_jsid($id);

        $data = array(
            'js_personal_title' => $this->input->post('title'),
            'js_personal_desc' => $this->input->post('decs'),
            'tbl_jobseeker_jobseeker_id' => $jid[0]['jobseeker_id'],
            'tbl_jobseeker_tbl_user_u_id'=>$id
        );
        // echo json_encode($data);

        $this->db->insert('tbl_js_personal',$data);
       echo  json_encode($data);
       exit;
    }
```

Comment: If you found out the error please do update what was it,curiosity to know what was the issue.